# Android App Not Responding the SMS Receiver

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have been working on an app to respond to received SMS messages (before you complain, I know this has been asked A LOT, but believe me, I can't get it to work at all, and I've tried searching for hours). I've got my manifest set up like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.csbctech.notiscreen"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".NotiScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="NotiScreenSmsReceiver" android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my receiver class looks like this:

```
package com.csbctech.notiscreen;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotiScreenSmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("NotiScreen", "Got SMS");

    }


}
```

But the "NotiScreenSmsReceiver" class never gets called. I've tried several different examples, and I can't for the life of me get the receiver class to get called...I've even tried removing the uses-permission, and I don't even get an error message about not having permissions. What could be wrong? Oh please help me, you're my only hope!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running this on a phone with a custom SMS app such as GOSMS? I've heard that some of those programs will stop the broadcast so that they can create their own notifications and stop the stock ones.

Comment: I am in fact running GOSMS on the phone too. I was wondering if that would be causing the issue...perhaps now I will investigate that further...thanks!

Comment: Now that I think about it, that would not be good if it didn't work for anybody that has GOSMS installed...is there some way to work around that? I already tried using a "priority" on the intent (I set it to 999999 or something crazy, just to try and see) but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Yeah they have the priority set to 2147483647, which is the largest value an integer can have! A way around it is to use a ContentObserver to observe the inbox instead of using the Broadcast. If you search on this site there are quite a lot of examples, hope it helps! By the way it might be worth testing it on the emulator to check that GOSMS is in fact causing the problem first!

Comment: The content observer is working, and was pretty easy to set up. I think I'll run with that...thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Change

`<receiver android:name="NotiScreenSmsReceiver" android:process=":remote">`

to

```
<receiver android:name=".NotiScreenSmsReceiver" android:process=":remote">
```