# Prioritize which app receives SMS

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I got an app that listens for SMSs and if a SMS has certain requirements it gets shown in my app, the thing is that this app works only if you don't have any launchers or SMS apps installed.

I tested this app on some of my friends phones and if they had GO luncher or GOMail or whatever app that listens for sms then my app won't show the SMS.

How can i prioritize so my app shows the SMS i want and not GoLuncher or other programs.

Comment: we need some code or some architecture, are you polling for the sms or juste using notifications ?

Comment: i use a class thats extends BroadcastReceiver and when i receive the SMS i use an Intent and send it to an Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out a workaround posted by Matt Harris, he said that GoSms has the priority set to  2147483647, which is the largest value an integer can have! A way around it is to use a ContentObserver to observe the inbox instead of using the Broadcast.

More found here: [Android App Not Responding the SMS Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990642/android-app-not-responding-the-sms-receiver?rq=1)